# How to group similar information on a certain column

Tags: mysql

```
create table forum (id, name, ...)
create table forum_comments (id, forum_id, comment, user_id, ...)
```

We would like to moderate forum comments, so that user cannot post the same comment multiple times say within the last 1 hour window. How should I do this?

Comment: Add a `BOOLEAN` column to `forum_comments` to flag whether the comment has been moderated, and only display those that have?

Comment: Yes we could moderate comments in the forum, but I would like a view on who is posting repeat information. Shouldn't that be possible, I am not sure of the solution